# Python Mysqldb update operation with variables

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a (maybe very simple) question, but I do not find the solution myself...

The database includes links. These include numbers. 
Now I want to insert in a separate column "nummer" the number that is included in each of the links.

Below works for one number.

Now I want to use a for-loop over several numbers and extract the number from all the links and write it into the "Nummer" field.

How to modify using %i or %d?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="192.168.0.101",
    db='xxxxxxx',
    user="xxxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxx"
    )
connection.apilevel = "2.0"
connection.threadsafety = 2
connection.paramstyle = "format" 

cursor=connection.cursor()

sql="UPDATE analysen SET Nummer = 247687  WHERE `Link` like '%247687%'"  
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a for loop over several numbers, it's just `for n in numbers:`.

The only tricky bit is how to parameterize a `LIKE` query. The way to do it is to put a normal `%s` parameter into the query, then wrap the parameter *value* in `%` characters. So:

```
sql = "UPDATE analysen SET Nummer = %s WHERE Link like %s"
for n in numbers:
    cursor.execute(sql, [n, '%{}%'.format(n)])
```

Or:

```
sql = "UPDATE analysen SET Nummer = %s WHERE Link like %s"
cursor.executemany(sql, ([n, '%{}%'.format(n)] for n in numbers)
```